# Linux ftp server supporting millisecond timestamps in transferlog

Tags: linux, ftp, logging

I'm looking for an ftp server for linux that will satisfy the following constraints

- Should be able to log when a file transfer (STOR command) is initiated.
- Should be able to log the time taken for the data transfer to complete (the actual time spent transfering data as part of a STOR command).
- Both of the above log statements should have millisecond accuracy

Does any ftp server have these features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProFTPD did not, until seeing your post, have this capability.  However, I filed it as a [feature request](http://bugs.proftpd.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4218), and the code implementing this has been merged.  So now I'm happy to say that proftpd would meet your needs/requirements.